# How to use a reactive table output from Shiny in a Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, reactive

I've got a Shiny application which allow to download a Rmarkdown word document but I don't know how to setup the table in this Rmarkdown.

Ui.R

```
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      title = "Résultat",
      br(),
      tableOutput(
        outputId = "tab"
      ),
      downloadButton(
        outputId = "downloadtable",
        label = "Export this table"
      ),
      radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                   inline = TRUE),
      downloadButton(
        outputId = "downloadReport",
        label = "Download"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Server.R

```
resu <- reactive({...
})

# Table of selected dataset
  output$tab <- renderTable({
  resu()
})
```

Report.rmd

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Aleksik"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---

## Resultat

```{r, echo=FALSE }
resu()
```
````

Output

```
##   Variable  IC 95% - IC 95% +
## 1 A            24.184   23.190   26.899
## 2 B           21.472   20.429   22.703
## 3 C             2.712    2.355    5.068
## 4 D            7.065    5.990   16.061
```

I would like to get a nice table without "##" for example.

Furthermore, option 'landscape' of my Rmarkdown document doesn't work and I don't know why.

Many thanks

Comment: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-7.html - try googling 'r markdown pretty tables'

Comment: As for landscape, you describe it as a Word document but you have `output: pdf_document` set? The orientation argument doesn't work for Word but there are workarounds eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719576/unable-to-produce-landscape-orientation-microsoft-word-document-from-r-markdown

Comment: Many thanks, just add kable(resu()), it's perfect.