# I cannot seem to get my rMarkdown code to honour the styles in my reference_docx document

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, page-layout

I am trying to output a word document and use the reference document to force landscape orientation and a specific table format as the default. I even tried to add the line - classoption: landscape. I am relatively new to R so please be gentle with me.
my test code is

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "my name"
date: "May 2021"
output: word_document
reference_docx: TestFormat.docx
classoption: landscape
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown
This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with `word_document` output. But a couple of years ago table formating did not persist through the `reference_docx` document. The combination of the packages `officer` and `flextable` is excellent for formating tables for MS Word output.

Comment: See this question for a possible solution to your orientation problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719576/unable-to-produce-landscape-orientation-microsoft-word-document-from-r-markdown