# R markdown landscape-only word document

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, officedown

I am trying to knit an `.Rmd` file to a word document that is entirely in landscape format.
Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719576/unable-to-produce-landscape-orientation-microsoft-word-document-from-r-markdown), I have tried using a reference doc. I created a Word document, changed the layout to landscape and saved it in the same folder as the `.Rmd`. However, this doesn't seem to work for me. Maybe I am missing something and saving a file in landscape format is not enough?

Previously, I was using the HTML comments/tags `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->` and `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->` from `{officedown}`, but since those can only be placed before and after code chunks, the title of the document would end up on a separate page that is portrait. Also, it gives a last page that is blank and portrait and that I don't know how to get rid of.

The current YAML header looks as follows:

```
---
title: "Summary Report"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: landscape_template.docx
---
```

I am also sure that the reference file is used because I get a warning in the console about not having set a Figure style:

```
Warning message:
paragraph style for plots "Figure" has not been found in the reference_docx document. Style 'Normal' will be used instead.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[After reaching out to the developer of `{officedown}` on GitHub](https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/discussions/88#discussioncomment-3670315), here is the very simple solution to the problem:

YAML header of .Rmd file:

```
---
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    page_size:
      orient: "landscape"
---
```